# How to build a specific component(s) with autotools?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I am using autotools with a tree that is composed of several different components of the same project with various libs that are shared between the differnet components. The intention is to have the components separated and built on different platforms w/ different architectures, but currently the entire project is a single tree and everything builds all at once for x86_64.

I'd like to be able to specifiy which component I'd like to make for the platform it will be run on, build, and install it. For example, in my thinking it might look something like the following:

```
$ cd componentA-BUILD
$ ../my-proj/configure --prefix=/install/A/here
$ make componentA
$ make install
```

The above should build componentA for x86_64 and install it in the location for which it was configured.

```
$ cd componentB-BUILD
$ ../my-proj/configure --prefix=/install/B/here
$ make componentB
$ make install
```

This should build componentB for ARM and install it in the prefix location for which it was configured (I haven't yet learned cross-compiling with autotools).

Comment: I am missing the question. The architecture for crossbuilding is usually passed as a configure parameter. see http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Cross_002dCompilation.html

Comment: Forget the cross-compiling, I'll take it step by step. The question is how to build specific components in a tree of many components. So if it contains component A, B, and C, how do I just build component A? The way I currently have it, is the entire tree builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not perfectly what you are trying to achieve, my suggestion is to use the `autoconf`'s variable `$host` (or `$target`, if you are cross-compiling).

For example add in your `configure.ac` the lines:

```
case $host in
  x86_64-*-linux-gnu*)
    COMPDIRS="componentA"
    AC_PREFIX_DEFAULT(/install/A/here)
  ;;
  i386-*-linux-gnu*)
    COMPDIRS="componentB componentC"
    AC_PREFIX_DEFAULT(/install/B/here)
  ;;
esac
AC_SUBST(COMPDIRS)
```

Also alter your `SUBDIRS` variable of root `Makefile.am` like:

```
SUBDIRS = $(COMPDIRS)
```

In the above example, the `COMPDIR` get different values depending to the host system. Then this variable is passed as the `SUBDIRS` definition.

Also you can use `AC_PREFIX_DEFAULT` according to each system.